# iOS 9 Defer location update not working

Tags: ios, core-location, ios9

Hi recently with the iOS 9 GM seed version out,I have seen location update(allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:timeout:) not getting deferred. I am getting error kCLErrorDeferredFailed - The location manager did not enter deferred mode for an unknown reason.

Its because of this error its not entering the defer mode at all and location updates are firing continuously .
The same code used to work in iOS 8.4 and below versions.Its draining my device's battery by a huge percentage.
Is there anything we need to explicitly set or mention for iOS 9.Didn't find anything from Apple documentation?

```
  -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

  if (!self.deferringUpdates) {

  [self.locationManager allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:CLLocationDistanceMax timeout:30];
   self.deferringUpdates = YES;
 } 
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didFinishDeferredUpdatesWithError:(NSError *)error {
  // Stop deferring updates
  self.deferringUpdates = NO;

 }
```

I also set the allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates property but even that didn't help.

```
      self.locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates=YES;
```

In iOS 9 and later, regardless of deployment target, you must also set the allowsBackgroundLocationUpdatesproperty of the location manager object to YES in order to receive background location updates. By default, this property is NO, and it should remain this way until a time when your app actively requires background location updates.

[Reduce Location Accuracy and Duration](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/LocationBestPractices.html)

Please let me know what additional I need to make

Thanks

Comment: Did you set the accuracy to best and distanceFilter to none ?

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [discussion](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620547-allowdeferredlocationupdatesunti?language=objc) on the API reference page.

A few things to try, as mentioned [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5521)

- Kill all apps from multitasking bar
- Verify that no other app is using location services
- Unplug the device from debugger and MacBook (Verify it is still getting call by logging didUpdateLocations to a file)
- Make sure that the device supports deferred updates
- Make sure that the distanceFilter is None, the desiredAccuracy is Best